# c program does not print anything

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, malloc

I have been having trouble with this program for a few days and I have decided to see if anyone could help me or give me hints as to why its not working. I am trying to do a program that will take the user input and then print it back to the user ( I am really trying to do a sort of text editor but I am doing it one step at a time to make sure I understand all the parts). I have not given a max of lines, I'd like the user to be able to write as many lines as he/she would like to thats why I am using malloc, and realloc after to readjust the necessary memory:

The problem I am having is that it doesn't print anything

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LEN  1000

int main(void)
{

  int totalLines = 0;
  char content[MAX_LEN + 1];
  char **arrays;
  int i = 0;

  printf("Enter your text to be edited\n");

  while (content[0] != '.') {
    fgets(content, MAX_LEN, stdin);
    content[strlen(content) - 1] = '\0';

    arrays = malloc(sizeof(char *) * totalLines);
    for (i = 0; i < totalLines; i++) {
      arrays[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(content) + 1));
      strcpy(arrays[i], content);
    }

    if (totalLines >= 1) {
      arrays = realloc(arrays, sizeof(char *) * totalLines);
      for (i = 0; i < totalLines; i++) {
        arrays[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(content) + 1));
        strcpy(arrays[i], content);
      }
      totalLines++;

    }
  }

  /* after user presses '.' the following is excuted: */

  for (i = 0; i < totalLines; i++) {
    printf("%s", arrays[i]);
  }
  int k;
  for (k = 0; k <= totalLines; k++) {
    free(arrays[k]);
  }
  free(arrays);
  arrays = NULL;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `arrays = realloc(arrays, sizeof(char *) * totalLines); ... totalLines++; ... for (k = 0; k <= totalLines; k++) {
  free (arrays[k]);` looks suspicious.  Maybe off-by 1 (or 2) when doing `free()`?

Comment: `while (content[0] != '.') {
   fgets(content, MAX_LEN, stdin);
   content[strlen(content)-1] = '\0';
` is certainly amiss.  Cheeking the return value of `fgets()` is a good improvement.

Comment: I checked the fgets and it is returning the correct value

Comment: Code is not checking the return value of `fgets()` and it may not _always_ return the correct value.

Comment: Is there anywhere else you could see where the problem is?

Comment: strlen() won't work if the string it's "len'ing" is not already null terminated. It will just keep counting until it hits a 0 character somewhere in memory. Therefore, when `content[strlen(content) - 1] = '\0';` executes, you might be overwriting a byte that shouldn't be. This is called a buffer overrun.

Comment: You code did not initialize the content array.  The compiler might not have initialized it for you, you should initialize it to be safe. You could simply do content[0] = '\0' before the while loop.

Comment: I would have used calloc() instead of malloc() to allocate memory for an array. calloc also has the nice side effect of initializing the allocated memory for you.

Comment: The first time thru your while loop you encounter arrays = malloc(sizeof(char *) * totalLines) and totalLines at this point is 0. Is that what you really want to do, to malloc(0) ? I don't think you want to do that.